# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'inRange'

Tags: python, opencv

I just built the opencv and tried one lane detection script. Script fails with the error message "AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'inRange'".

Has my build failed or is there something I am still missing?

Code is from someone elses github: https://github.com/georgesung/road_lane_line_detection

Comment: we can't know without seeing your code...

Comment: Please add [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added code to original post

Comment: You should at least try to do a small example using inRange and test that to see if it fails ... Do not expect people to follow a link, read 300 or more lines of code to find what possibly could be wrong in your configuration which we do not even have a clue about... try telling which version you have and how it was installed and possibly the system and any other detail

Comment: What is the script you executed to get this error? as long as opencv was built and imported correctly, `cv2.inRange()` should not give this error. can you open an interpreter, import cv2 and check if you get the same issue?

Comment: It seems that you forget to install opencv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could have the wrong version of OpenCV. Inside a python console run

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

if the version is 2.x that is likely your problem. `cv2.inRange()` definitely works for the recent OpenCV versions `3.2.0 +`.

Comment: It seems that I cannot do anything with this module:


    AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: Seems your OpenCV is not set up correctly. I would reinstall OpenCV in that case. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using raspbian

Comment: maybe check you have the libs with `pkg-config --libs opencv` in terminal. 
Pyimagesearch has pretty good tutorials for raspberry pi and opencv: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/